# Setting up Constants in Ethereum smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens

I am looking for the best way to use the constants in Ethereum smart contract for my ERC20. I am currently doing the following

```
contract MyST is ERC20, Prefixed {
constructor() ERC20("MyST", "MST") {
 // _mint
 }
}
```

Where the `Prefixed` is

```
abstract contract Prefixed is Context {
function _walletAddress() internal virtual returns (address){
  return 0x*************; // address
 }
}
```

And then use it in my contract like `address coreAddress = _walletAddress();`

It gets the job done but is this the proper way to do it? or can I improve the method of using some really necessary consts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use library.

Example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

library Roles {
    bytes32 public constant CONFIG_ROLE = keccak256("CONFIG_ROLE");
}
```

Then:

```
import "./Roles.sol";
contract Demo {
   function test() public {
      require(hasRole(Roles.CONFIG_ROLE, msg.sender), "forbidden");
   }
}
```